# What happens if you don't return a promise and only use resolve?

Tags: javascript, promise

In other words, what happen if I do this:

```
const setBuildingPayload = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.buildingForm.schema.forEach(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve()
    }, 3000)
  })
})
```

Instead of this?

```
const setBuildingPayload = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  return this.buildingForm.schema.map(() => {
    return setTimeout(() => {
      resolve()
    }, 3000)
  })
})
```

I ask this because I was surprised when using `setBuildingPayload` in `Promise.all` without return worked (the code inside `Promise.all` triggered after `resolve()`.

And I thought every promise should return its value.

Comment: none of the returns in the second code block are required - because asynchronous code

Comment: It does matter when you're chaining promises - if you're calling a thenable in the executor of a `then` call, you need to return it, otherwise the *next* call to then will be executed immediately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function in question, `(resolve, reject) => {...}`, is called an *executor* function for the `Promise`. As per the last sentence in [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Parameters) for the *executor*

> The return value of the executor is ignored

This can be demonstrated using this simple piece of code (modified from the example provided)

```js
const setBuildingPayload = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve("Done");
  }, 1000);
  return 100;
});

setBuildingPayload.then(result => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Notice how `return 100` didn't make any difference. Hence, the returns in your second piece of code make no difference as well.

Answer (score 1):

The `return this.buildingForm.schema.map` has no impact on how the Promise resolves. Its an unused return value and what our team likes to call "for funsies".